# R autoKrige loop (package automap)

Tags: r, loops, automap

I have a data frame with daily observations, which I would like to interpolate. I use automap to build a variogram for every days and then apply on new data. I try to run a loop and put the results in a new dataframe. Unfortunately, the data frame with the results only contains the last predicted day.

```
coordinates(mydata) <- ~lat+long
coordinates(new_data) <- ~lat+long
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=50,ncol=10)) #new data frame for predicted valeus

for(i in 1:ncol(mydata))
    kriging_new <- autoKrige(mydata[,i],mydata,newdata)
    pred <- kriging_new$krige_output$var1.pred
    df[,i] <- data.frame(pred)
```

The result looks like this, all the columns should be filled with values, not just the last one:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9       X10
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 12.008726
2  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  6.960499
3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 10.894787
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 14.378945
5  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 17.719522
```

I also get a warning, saying:

```
Warning message:
In autofitVariogram(formula, data_variogram, model = model, kappa = kappa,  :
  Some models where removed for being either NULL or having a negative sill/range/nugget, 
    set verbose == TRUE for more information
```

If I do autoKrige manually for each row, everything works fine. It seems the loop is not working as it usually does. Is this some problem in the automap package?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot to enclose the code in your `for` loop in curly brackets. As a result you execute the loop 10 times, overwriting `kriging_new` with itself every time:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mydata))
    kriging_new <- autoKrige(mydata[,i],mydata,newdata)
```

Only then do you assign the result from your **last** iteration:

```
pred <- kriging_new$krige_output$var1.pred
```

and finally assign those to the last column of your data frame holding your predictions (the loop counter `i` is still set to 10 at this point):

```
df[, i] <- data.frame(pred)
```

Always write loops with multiple lines of statements like this:

```
for (condition) {
    statement1
    statement2
    ...
}
```

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot! Tried to figure this out for too long, must have been totally brackets blind :-) It works now!